# Something/Someone is (not) there

Tags: subject-verb-inversion

My (Italian) students tend to produce sentences like:

When I arrived, there weren't my parents (as opposed to 'my parents were not there')

I cannot think of a grammar rule to provide an explanation. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

As FumbleFingers notes, the problem is that "there" and "ci" are not interchangeable although they both have a similar double role.

To simplify, you could tell your students that "there are" or "there is" usually means "to exist" like "esserci", while to mean "there" as in a specific place they have to use it like "lì"/"là".

I miei genitori non c'erano → my parents were not there ← i miei genitori non erano là.